# Looking for a Discworld book a quote is from (and the full quote)

Tags: story-identification, quotes, discworld, terry-pratchett

I've been thinking about a quote from one of the Discworld books which went something like (from memory and not in the tone of Terry):

> The thing about insurmountable mountains is that they are until they aren't. And then a generation after that old ladies will stroll up to its peak as an afternoon stroll.

What I took away from it was that things are really hard until someone does it the first time, and then it gets a lot easier since there's a way.

Anyone know which book this might be from? Or what the real quote was?

Comment: Closest I've found is [“I wonder if it's like this for mountain climbers, he thought. You climb bigger and bigger mountains and you know that one day one of them is going to be just that bit too steep. But you go on doing it, because it’s so-o good when you breathe the air up there. And you know you'll die falling.”](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/428310-i-wonder-if-it-s-like-this-for-mountain-climbers-he)

Comment: Makes me think *Witches Abroad* but a quick run on an ebook doesn't find it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is from [Maskerade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maskerade), in relation to Greebo the cat's transformation into a human.

The allusion is that it's very hard to do something once (e.g. turn a cat into a man) but that once it had happened, it was infinitely easier to accomplish *again*.

> But magic is never as simple as people think. It has to obey certain universal laws. And one is that, no matter how hard a thing is to do, once it has been done it’ll become a whole lot easier and will therefore be done a lot. **A huge mountain might be scaled by strong men only after many centuries of failed attempts, but a few decades later grandmothers will be strolling up it for tea and then wandering back afterward to see where they left their glasses.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Maskerade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maskerade)</sup></sub>

Comment: Heh.  Just a few minutes more to troll through the entire Witches series and I would have had it.  Nice find.

Comment: @Radhil - I used a different tactic. I searched through every Pratchett book for the word "strolling".

Comment: The original thing quotes sounded more like it came from a Tiffany Aching book or from Equal Rites so I completely didn't even search my brain for things in books with Agnes Nitt in them ^.^

Comment: @Valorum - I was keying off "mountain" just for this series, but I was still too slow to sift through it all.

Comment: @Durakken - The joy of using [calibre library](https://calibre-ebook.com/) with the [Quality Check](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125428) plugin is that I can search all 41 Discworld novels for a particular word or phrase in 0.1 seconds

Comment: @Valorum Meh. I prefer to rely on my memory to find quotes and then transcribe them by hand from paper books. Much more impressive.

Comment: @randal'thor - Bah, paper? In my day you needed to translate them from Greek parchments into English first.

Comment: @Valorum When I were a lad, we used to dream of having Greek parchments to copy. We used to have to write the books ourselves first so we could post quotes from them! (Btw, hope you appreciate the Buffy gifs I'm finding and posting in chat in your honour ;-) )

Comment: @randal'thor - Animated gifs? In my day you used to have to watch shadows on the cave walls for entertainment.

Comment: Don't write things down, Haven't you learned that if you're not a mage writing things can be very dangerous? Just ask the librarian... either one will do. The nerdy ones are probably easier to understand than the Gorilla.

Comment: Parchment, you were lucky, we only had stone tablets

Comment: @Valorum Do deformed rabbit, it's my favourite!

Comment: @Stevetech Dammit, you beat me to that... Then again, [Physicists set the universal constants to make the universe evolve into a state of containing the information they want](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Comment: @Stevetech You young folks have it easy, with your fanciful stone tablets. Back in my day, we didn't have portable stone. We had to carve the things directly into our eyeballs with blunt stalagmites and if you messed up, you had to gouge out those of the family pet and jam them into your own head.

Comment: Bah, in my day you needed to sharpen a reed at an angle and press it into wet clay. Gods help you if you needed to make a note when it was raining or snowing! And then you needed to bake it! And the durned language was a mixture of letters, pictographs, characters, scholarly shorthand- it was no wonder we would scrawl a prayer not to mess up on the top!